# WPF SelectedValue of combobox not updating from viewmodel property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have the following combobox in my MainWindow:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding LanguageId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"/>
```

in my ViewModel i have the following two properties set:

```
public List<Language> Languages
{
  get
  {
    return new List<Language>()
    {
     new Language { Id = 0, Name = ml.ml_string(100, "Language1") },
     new Language { Id = 1, Name = ml.ml_string(101, "Language2") },
     new Language { Id = 2, Name = ml.ml_string(102, "Language3") },
     new Language { Id = 3, Name = ml.ml_string(103, "Language4") }
    };
  }
}

public int LanguageId
{
  get
  {
    return _languageId;
  }
  set
  {
    _languageId = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Languages");
    NotifyPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

So what i want is to notify my Languages property after i select a language in the combobox but currently when i do this, it shows no value at all(see picture):
[combobox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRcmt.png)
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need this? ```NotifyPropertyChanged("Languages");```

Comment: The selected item has to equal to an item in the collection. You always return a collection of new objects from `Languages`, so when the selection changes, you set ItemsSource to a new collection which does not contain the object that was just selected. So the ComboBox discards the selected item value as invalid. You could fix this by overriding `Equals(Language)` on `Language`, or (much better) by keeping your `Languages` around permanently and reusing them.

Comment: I need to do this because i change the language of the application in this way and the items in the combobox also need to be translated.

Comment: I'm using a extended multi language tool which lookups the translated value. (updated my code)

Comment: Change list to ObservableCollection and try again

Comment: Changing it to ObserableCollection didnt help for me but thanks for the feedback @NareshRavlani.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected item has to be considered equal to an item in the collection. However, you always return a collection of new objects from `Languages`, so when the selection changes, you set `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to a new collection which does not contain the object that was just selected. So the `ComboBox` discards the selected item value as invalid. Using `SelectedValuePath` doesn't work around this issue, as you found.

You could fix this by overriding `Equals(Language)` on `Language`, or (much better) by keeping your `Languages` around permanently and reusing them.

If you need to translate the `Name` property, you could do that [with a value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

The reason I advise against overriding `Equals()` is that in C#, you get in the habit of assuming that comparing two instances of a reference type means `Object.ReferenceEquals()`, and breaking that assumption can cause bugs. I speak from experience.

Since we're no longer using the `Name` property, we can just change `Languages` into a `List<int>` of Language Ids -- in which case we can make it readonly and never bother to recreate the list. I've done that here.

```
public class LanguageNameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is int)
        {
            var itemLanguageId = (int)values[0];
            var displayLanguageId = (int)values[1];

            //  Do stuff here to get the translated name of the item language
            var itemLanguageNameTranslated = $"Name of language {itemLanguageId} in language {displayLanguageId}";

            return itemLanguageNameTranslated;
        }
        else return values[0]?.GetType();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox 
    SelectedValue="{Binding LanguageId}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label>
                <Label.Content>
                    <MultiBinding 
                        Converter="{StaticResource LanguageNameConverter}"
                        >
                        <Binding Path="." />
                        <Binding 
                            Path="DataContext.LanguageId" 
                            RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}" 
                            />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Content>
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If you'd prefer to keep the `Language` class in `Languages`, just restore `SelectedValuePath="Id"` on the ComboBox, and set the `Path` of the first `Binding` in the `MultiBinding` to `Id` instead of `.`.

```
<ComboBox 
    SelectedValue="{Binding LanguageId}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    ...
```

...

```
<MultiBinding 
    Converter="{StaticResource LanguageNameConverter}"
    >
    <Binding Path="Id" />
    <Binding 
        Path="DataContext.LanguageId" 
        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}" 
        />
</MultiBinding>
```

---

## Equals-override solution

Here's the `Equals()` solution; we tried it but it had a problem with keeping the old SelectedItem, with its old name in a previously selected language, after the selection changed. That's because of the `Equals()` override thing. So we went with the multi-value converter, which doesn't need any workarounds or funny business.

Just do things the way WPF wants, and nobody gets hurt. That's the rule.

```
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Language)
        {
            return ((Language)obj).Id == Id;
        }
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

If you choose this solution, you will also need to add a recursion guard to your `LanuageId` property:

```
private int _languageId;
public int LanguageId
{
    get
    {
        return _languageId;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_languageId != value)
        {
            _languageId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Languages");
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing `ComboBox.ItemsSource` will now cause the actual `SelectedItem` to change to a new object instance, which update `SelectedValue`, which will cause `LanguageId` to be set again -- to the same value it already has. If you omit the recursion guard, `LanguageId`'s `set` block will raise `PropertyChanged` for `Languages` once again, which will update `SelectedItem`, etc. -- and we're off to the races until the stack overflows.

Comment: Thanks Ed, this did the trick for me, only problem is that the correct value is shown but it's only translated correct in the combo list and not in the value field. But that is something i need to figure out myself :).

Comment: The value field?

Comment: *In the combobox itself. In the combobox itself it shows the right language name but not translated and in the dropdown menu it shows the correct translation.

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it now. What's happening is it updates `SelectedItem`, finds that that object `Equals()` one of the objects in `ItemsSource`, and keeps it. So it's got the old `SelectedItem` object from the old language. This is an example of the kind of funhouse-mirror stuff you get when you override `Equals` on a reference type. So, how to fix...

Comment: 1. Add a `Language SelectedLanguage { /* INPC stuff */ }` property bound to `ComboBox.SelectedItem`, and when you change the LanguageId, update `SelectedLanguage` with the appropriate item from the new collection.

Comment: 2. Use a multi-value converter to look up the language names in the currently selected language. This solution will work without any funny business or workarounds; it's the way WPF is designed to be used, and doing things the way WPF likes them done is always the path of least agony. The language Ids don't change when the selected language changes, right?

Comment: No the id's dont change, i only need to call that ml.ml_string function so it looks up the right value again. I will try to setup a multi-value converter this sounds like the right way.

Comment: @ThomasV I tested that solution, so I'll just paste that into my answer.

Comment: Oke thanks Ed, i assume that overriding the Equals is then not needed anymore?

Comment: Thanks @EdPlunkett your a legend! =]